# Codeception acceptance tests are slow

Tags: mysql, laravel, selenium, codeception

I'm new to codeception. I use selenium + firefox for acceptance tests.

As I got it since each test should be independent codeception reloads mysql dump after each test.

I got two simple tests, one for login and another one for registering a new user. It takes 1 minute for these two tests. Also I realize that most time firefox just stays untouched without any actions, looks like it takes a lot of time to reload mysql dump.

If I have 100-200 tests it'll take hours. How can I make them faster?
I wanted to use db transcations but I don't know how to do that, like populating DB only once and then rollback after each test. Is it possible?

Btw I use Laravel 5, but as I got it it doesn't matter for acceptance tests

Comment: How large is your mysql dump? Make it smaller.

Comment: It's not large at all. I mean, it's almost empty DB with ~50 records. Which looks strange

Comment: Set `cleanup: false` parameter for Db module, then Db won't be reloaded before each test.

Comment: Yeah but then tests won't be independent?

Comment: It is a trade off. Make your tests use different items to avoid conflicts.